# Insert message in Azure Queue using Service SAS Token

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, message-queue, shared-access-signatures

This is my first time working with SAS. I am trying to access the azure queues using Service Sas Token and trying to insert a message but it is not working. When I try to access the generated URI from browser then I am getting below error

"The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb. RequestId:cc1f2356-f003-0015-78b6-15f337000000 Time:2023-11-12T22:23:52.3942771Z".
What could be the problem? Below is my sample code

Note: I will replace queueName, AccountName and AccountKey with original values.

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<BlobServiceClient>> GetServiceQueueSasToken()
{
ApiResponse<BlobServiceClient> result = new ApiResponse<BlobServiceClient>();
try
{

string queueName = "queueName";
string accountName = "accountName";
string accountKey = "accountKey";
StorageSharedKeyCredential storageSharedKeyCredential = new(accountName, accountKey);

var serviceQueueUri = new Uri($"https://{accountName}.queue.core.windows.net/{queueName}");
string sasToken = await CreateServiceQueueSASToken(storageSharedKeyCredential, queueName);
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClientAccountSAS = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"{serviceQueueUri}?  {sasToken}"));

SendMessageUsingSasToken(blobServiceClientAccountSAS.Uri queueName, sasToken);

result.Data = blobServiceClientAccountSAS;
result.IsSucceed = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
result.IsSucceed = false;
result.Exception = ex;
result.ErrorMessages = new List<string>();
result.ErrorMessages.Add(ex.Message);
}
return result;
}

public static async Task<string> CreateServiceQueueSASToken(StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKey, string   queueName)
{
 var queueSasBuilder = new QueueSasBuilder()
 {
 QueueName = queueName,
 ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
 Protocol = SasProtocol.Https
 };

queueSasBuilder.SetPermissions(QueueSasPermissions.Add | QueueSasPermissions.Read);

string sasToken = queueSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(sharedKey).ToString();

return sasToken;
}

static void SendMessageUsingSasToken(Uri serviceUri, string queueName, string sasToken)
{
 var queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceUri, queueName, sasToken);
 queueClient.SendMessage("Your message content", sasToken);
 Console.WriteLine("Message sent successfully.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with using the SAS token in your `SendMessageUsingSasToken` method. The `QueueClient` constructor already expects the SAS token to be included in the URI, so you don't need to pass it again as a parameter when creating the `QueueClient`.

The code below generates a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token for an Azure Storage Queue and uses it to send a message to the specified queue.

```cs
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Queues;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;
using Azure.Storage.Shared;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; } = default!;
    public bool IsSucceed { get; set; }
    public Exception? Exception { get; set; }
    public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var response = GetServiceQueueSasToken().Result; // Blocking call
        if (response.IsSucceed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SAS token generated successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.Exception?.Message}");
        }
    }

    public static async Task<ApiResponse<QueueServiceClient>> GetServiceQueueSasToken()
    {
        ApiResponse<QueueServiceClient> result = new ApiResponse<QueueServiceClient>();
        try
        {
            string queueName = "AzurequeueName";
            string accountName = "AzureStorageAccountName ";
            string accountKey = "AzureStorageAccountAccountKey";

            StorageSharedKeyCredential storageSharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);

            var serviceQueueUri = new Uri($"https://{accountName}.queue.core.windows.net");
            string sasToken = CreateServiceQueueSASToken(storageSharedKeyCredential, queueName);

            QueueServiceClient queueServiceClient = new QueueServiceClient(new Uri($"{serviceQueueUri}?{sasToken}"));

            SendMessageUsingSasToken(queueServiceClient, queueName);

            result.Data = queueServiceClient;
            result.IsSucceed = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.IsSucceed = false;
            result.Exception = ex;
            result.ErrorMessages = new List<string> { ex.Message };
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static string CreateServiceQueueSASToken(StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKey, string queueName)
    {
        var queueSasBuilder = new QueueSasBuilder
        {
            QueueName = queueName,
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            Protocol = SasProtocol.Https
        };

        queueSasBuilder.SetPermissions(QueueSasPermissions.Add | QueueSasPermissions.Read);

        string sasToken = queueSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(sharedKey).ToString();

        return sasToken;
    }

    static void SendMessageUsingSasToken(QueueServiceClient queueServiceClient, string queueName)
    {
        var queueClient = queueServiceClient.GetQueueClient(queueName);
        queueClient.SendMessage("Your message content");
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]